# iOS Circle Gesture + Highlight Text

Tags: ios, highlight

I have a custom gesture that detects when a user draws a circle. Once the gesture is successful, I want it so that all the text within the circle is highlighted. One idea I had was to create a UIBeziarPath, but I couldn't figure out how to highlight the text that it enclosed.

Comment: Could you draw a picture of what the desired effect should look like?

Comment: Well in the usual iOS text selection paradigm (press and hold text then a copy/paste menu comes up). I'd like that same behaviour except it highlights the text within the circle.

Comment: The usual paradigm is to select a portion of text in a range starting at some character and ending at another. If a circle covers several lines of text it will produce several disjoint ranges. Or is your text always one line?

Comment: Ideally, I can select several disjoint regions, but if the only way it can work is one continuous region then that is fine too.

Comment: -setSelectionRange should do just fine, though I have no idea how you could get the ranges...